# How to compile MapBox SDK

Tags: android, mapbox

I am a Android Developer.

Recently, I was working on the compilation of MapBox SDK.

I want to follow the [official website](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/INSTALL.md#additional-dependencies-for-macos) steps，But I developed it on Windows，
I want to change the source code，instead of just using aar.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFKF8.jpg)
So,Can someone tell me what to do?thank you.

Yesterday I tried to import the mapbox project,download CMake,cUrl..,I find the build.gradle of module，There is a note：

```
// Load build system information. If this file does not exist, run
// `make platform/android/configuration.gradle`
```

apply from: rootProject.file('configuration.gradle')

make,it's linux command，I use the windows system,so I download the MinGW.
but when I use this command to build configuration.gradle, i got failed:

```
make:***FATAL***platform/android/configuration.gradle:unknown action keyword
```

so i tried to use this code in android studio Terminal,but it can't use make、cmake or other,so how can i build this file.

I've been getting this mistake：

```
Error:(22, 0) Could not read script 'F:\AndroidStudio\AndroidStudio_WorkSpace\mapbox-gl-native-master\platform\android\configuration.gradle' as it does not exist.
```

or someone has ever done this,could you give me your configuration.gradle,so i can modify it.

thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't describe it in more detail, because my language is not very good。Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to compile the SDK in Windows. The easiest way is to use CMake from within Android Studio. Note however that CMake support is only for the 64 bit version (I believe) not for the 32 bit version of Studio.

If you're building from the command line, then 32 bit or 64 bit both work because NDK is available for either. To do that, you'd write something like:

```
./gradlew.bat -Pmapbox.buildtype=debug -Pmapbox.abis=all :MapboxGLAndroidSDKTestApp:assembleDebug
```

Comment: hello,thank you for you opinion,I tried a lot of ways，and I found that I hadn't even started compiling SDK, and I was stuck in the steps of building the project, i can't build the 'configuration.gradle'，i don't know what to do。